# Count total number of cell filled and multiply

Tags: excel-formula

I wanted to ask of it’s possible to create formula in excel to count the total number of cell populated and multiply it with another cell?

Example:
I have 4 weeks and only 3 weeks are filled i want to automatically multiply it by 3.

Then once week 4 is filled out it will multiply by 4

[this is what I was trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7M7E.png)

Comment: Please show at least your current data structure otherwise we won't be able to suggest a formula - see [ask] and [repro]

Comment: `=counta( [your cells] ) * [your other cell]`

Answer (score 1):

[image: Excel Count]

Hi this is what I have tried hope it helps and might give you insights.12Rev79

Answer (score 0):

[image: Count Not null and multiply]

Or may be another suggestion could be like this